# Unable to get properties off navlink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm teaching myself React (using v18.1.0) and I'm struggling to understand why I am getting an undefined object off the properties I'm passing to a component through a NavLink using react-router-dom v.6.3.0.

I have a component that has a NavLink that is created when a certain variable (let's call it "var1") is not null, like so:

```
[...]
{
   var1 != null
   ?
   <NavLink className="Menu-Button" to={{pathname : "/Component1"}} state = {{ props : var1 }}>ButtonContent</NavLink>
   : <p/>
}
[...]
```

The component being routed to (let's call it "Component1") looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

const Component1= () => {

    const location = useLocation();
    const { props } = location;
    console.log(props);

    return(
    [...]
    )
};

export default Component1;
```

The output of that console.log is `undefined`. I've also tried using props.location instead of useLocation(), but I get the same issue. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:

Including route config in App.js as requested by @Nick Vu:
N.B. Toolbar is a component that acts as a header / navigator

```
[all the imports]

const App = () => {
  return (
     <BrowserRouter>
       <Toolbar />
       <Routes>
         [all the existing routes that work fine]
         <Route exact path='/Component1' element={<Component1 /> } />
       </Routes>
     </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `NavLink` seems good, but according to your setup, in `Component1`, you should access `props` values from `NavLink` by `state`.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

const Component1= () => {

    const location = useLocation();
    const props = location?.state?.props; //use `?` to avoid errors from missing states

    console.log(props)

    return(
    [...]
    )
};

export default Component1;
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/x-subdomain-test-site-2-forked-lot3jy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks , have tried but getting same outcome. I know the variable itself is not undefined, as if it were the component wouldn't be getting rendered

Comment: Could you show the part which is how you call `<Route>` for `Component1` in the question? @WT_W

Comment: You can verify the changes here https://codesandbox.io/s/x-subdomain-test-site-2-forked-lot3jy?file=/src/App.js @WT_W

Comment: Have updated, but my route config looks different to the snippet you have provided

Comment: You are also using react-router, I am using react-router-dom

Comment: I modified my code in sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/x-subdomain-test-site-2-forked-lot3jy?file=/src/components/Nav.jsx:269-297, could you verify it again? I think the part you are missing is using `location?.state?.props` to get `props` values from state

Comment: this is embarassing but I just found my problem. My original code was structured ok, but I had "state = {{ props : var1 }}" instead of "state={{props : var1}}". Once I changed that (with everything else original), I can see the object coming through now... Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

This was embarassing but, changing

```
state = {{ props : var1 }}
```

to

```
state={{props : var1}}
```

has resolved the issue.